# (Angular 6 + Postgres) Time input not working properly with db

Tags: html, angular, postgresql

I have this 'input' tag, where i have to put a time value (hours and minutes). I'm not using the HTML 5's "type = 'time' ", because my db receives a string (like 12:30), thus refusing the information (as postgres is expecting 'time without time-zone'). So, i'm just using a mask to put the ':' without actually sending them. But even without the mask, the db is not working properly.

For example, if i go to my field and input the value '120000'(12:00:00),

[image]

what postgres actually saves is this:

[image]

Then you think "Well, just add time using 8 characters, then", well, let's try using 13301500 (13:30:15.00):

[image]

The result:

[image]

I could show lots more of examples. If I input '1230', i get '21:00:01.23', if i input '13', i get '21:00:00.013'. Sometimes i can see my typed value in the end of the numbers in the db, but still, i'm very confused. What am I doing wrong here?

This is my button:

```
<div id="form" class="left">
    <input
    formControlName="start" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Start">
</div>
```

And this is my post method (API):

```
@PostMapping("/turn")
    public Turn add(@RequestBody @Valid Turn T) {
        return TurnRepo.save(T);
    }
```

As well as the variable:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "start", length = 15)
private Date start;
```

Comment: Can you try with `04:05:06.789` ?

Comment: The result is 08:15:06.789